# PHP str_replace for each occurence

Tags: php

I want to find :

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

Which is 12x on the page displayed.
and replace it with variable $myvalue, an array which holds 12 values.

first occurence :

```
<td>$myvalue[0]</td>
```

second occurence :

```
<td>$myvalue[1]</td>
```

ETC.

I need this in some sort foreach find function but don´t know how to figure this out with str_replace or preg_replace.

Anybody knows how to solve this ? Thanks.

Edit -> My new idea is :

```
$i=0;
foreach($myvalue as $value) {
str_replace('<td>$myvalue[$i]</td>',$new,$html);
$i++;
}
```

But I don't know how to only replace the first occurence found with str_replace.

Comment: On what page? The one you're generating from the same PHP script, or if something else then what?  Please show more details.

Comment: If this is an html string, consider using an HTML parser instead.

Comment: With a loop use [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) to find one and [substr_replace()](http://php.net/substr_replace) to replace, until strpos returns false.

Comment: Are you sure its an array?

Comment: @OIS Thanks that is a great answer, can you show me this alternative way.

Comment: @user3710844 something like: while(false !== $pos = strpos($text, $search)) { $text = substr_replace($text, $newtext, $pos, strlen($search)); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_match()` and iterate over the matches.

Edit: I find that [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) is a very nice way to write my regular expressions.

Try this:

```
<?
$matches = preg_match_all("/<td>&nbsp;<\/td>/", $input_lines, $output_array);
?>
```

Comment: He probably doesn't know regex.

Comment: Yes, you are right I tried it but I can not find the regex for it. I tried : /<td>&nbsp;</td>/

Comment: Thank you for saying what you tried! I added an example. You just needed to escape the `/`.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I'm getting it wrong but this puts all found matches in an array. I want to replace them and each time found I want to replace it with an different value.

Comment: That's a little tricky and I'm not totally sure but this seems like a decent starting point. You can iterate over the matches like this: `for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches); $i++)` but I'm not totally sure how to do the replacement. Hopefully someone else can help with that part.

Comment: Guess I have to use preg_replace like this : preg_replace("/<td>&nbsp;<\/td>/", "newtext", $html, $i); For example $i = 1

Comment: Huh. Nice find. Never have used that last argument. Cheers!

Comment: @user3710844 preg_replace_callback could work here too without limit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>';
$replacements = [1,2,3,4];

while ($replacements) {
    $text = preg_replace('/&nbsp;/', array_shift($replacements), $text, 1);
}
```

Test passed on 5.4.29.
Note this does not check for boundary conditions.